# Enabling Single Macro and Disabling All Others

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to just enable a single macro and disable all others in an Excel (2016, 365) worksheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Digitally sign the macro that you want to enable, and remove digital signatures from all other macros if such a signature was there.

Menu - File - options - trust center - trust center settings - macros settings
tick on "disable all macros except digitally signed ones"